# Visual Studio 2013 Click Once With SQL Server Express 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am struggling to find information on if it is possible to use command line arguments for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express when it's deployed as a prerequisite with an app. I would like to configure SQL Server Express for network connections and login password information.

I am thinking that that my objective probably can't be achieved with click once. Could I achieve this aim with the InstallShield setup project type?